# Android Intent FileProvider "Permision denied" to open KML file in Google Earth?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-earth, android-fileprovider

Before Android Nougat ( 7.0 ) it was easy to create a KML file in external storage and launch an intent with the file uri and Google Earth mime type for KML.  Google Earth app magically opened and flew down to my KML.

On Android Nougat ( 7.0 ) you must use a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) with the intent. You must add a provider to AndroidManifest.xml plus a /res/xml/provider_paths.xml.

Using the **FileProvider** intent, the installed **Google Earth** app will launch, then display message "Error loading file" in **Google Earth**.

**Logcat** displays "**FileNotFoundException Permission denied**".

**File: AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**File: /res/xml/provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

```
// File: MainActivity.java

// I used Android Device Monitor to push mooCow.kml to
//     /storage/emulated/0/Download/mooCow.kml
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File kmlFile =  new File(folder, "mooCow.kml");
    String pathToLocalKmlFile = kmlFile.getAbsolutePath();
    openKmlInGoogleEarth(pathToLocalKmlFile);
}
// This works with KML and file extensions supported by getMimeTypeFromExtension
public void openKmlInGoogleEarth(String pathToFileInExternalStorage) {
    try {
        String[] splits = pathToFileInExternalStorage.split("\\.");
        String ext = "";
        if(splits.length >= 2) {
            ext = splits[splits.length-1];
        }
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        File file = new File(pathToFileInExternalStorage);
        Uri uri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            // Use file Uri before Android Nougat ( 7.0 )
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } else {
            // Android Nougat ( 7.0 ) and later,
            // use a FileProvider, AndroidManifest provider, and /res/xml/provider_paths.xml
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    file);
        }
        final String type = "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected exception openKmlInGoogleEarth", e);
    }
}
```

**adb logcat** point to **com.google.android.apps.earth** permission problem.

How can Asus File manager app open the same exact file in Google Earth but my app cannot?  My non-FileProvider works fine on Android 5.2 but on Android 6 it only launches Google Earth?

```
E Class   : Error reading file from URI: content://com.subsite.googleearthbutton.provider/external_files/Documents/mooCow.kml
E Class   : java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
E Class   :     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
E Class   :     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:692)
E Class   :     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1104)
E Class   :     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:942)
E Class   :     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
E Class   :     at com.google.android.apps.earth.p.m.a(FileUtil.java:6)
```

What could be causing a file access "**Permission denied**" ?

[image]

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Comment: "On Android 6 I think I need to use a FileProvider" -- no, you could still use `Uri.fromFile()`, at least as far as the OS is concerned. On Android 7.0+ is where a `FileProvider` is required. Your `<uses-permission>` element is in the wrong place (needs to be outside of `<application>`). Beyond that, perhaps `pathToLocalKmlFile` does not exist. Also, is your LogCat entry coming from your app or from Google Earth?

Comment: `"${applicationId}.provider"` does that resolve to `"com.subsite.googleearthbutton.provider"`?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` Try without if you use no file provider.

Comment: @CommonsWare So I do *not* need a **FileProvider** on 6.0.  I pass `pathToLocalKmlFile` as argument to `openKmlInGoogleEarth`. I corrected post mistake and moved `<uses-permission>` outside of `<application>`. "Permission denied" is coming from com.google.android.apps.earth.p.m.a(FileUtil.java:6).  **Asus File Manager** can open the KML file somehow.  I cannot either with or without *FileProvider* but same code works fine on Android 5.1?

Comment: `readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel` suggests that your `FileProvider` is unable to serve your file (e.g., the file does not exist).

Comment: Correction: The non **FileProvider** intent works fine on an **Android 6 ARM device** but * NOT * an **x86 ARM Emulator**.  No clue why.  The file exists because File Manager could open it in Google Earth on the x86 emulator.  Maybe just an x86 quirk?  Anyway, I need to find a N device or try testing on an emulator to make sure the FileProvider intent will work.

Comment: How does `content://com.acmeinc.googleearthbutton.provider/external_files/Download/mooCow.kml` get resolved to `/storage/emulated/0/Download/mooCow.kml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I forgot to add a run-time check and request WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I think on older versions of Android all I had to do was add a `<uses-permission>` element to AndroidManifest.xml

I had neither **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** or **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** until I checked and requested.

Thank you all for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

For me, nowadays this is what worked:

`Uri uriFromFile = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, GenericFileProvider.class.getName(), file);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uriFromFile, "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
intent.putExtra("com.google.earth.EXTRA.tour_feature_id", "my_track");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: What does putExtra "com.google.earth.EXTRA.tour_feature_id" add?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943958/257948 please @EdoftheMountain